# unable to boot ubuntu or load from flash drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a windows 10 and ubuntu 14 dual boot on a test server.  After I restarted windows, the grub boot loader does not load up - I have tried pressing Shift when booting the server but no boot up options come up.  It does not seem to pick up the flash drive which has Ubuntu on it either.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?